# Checking matches for arrays of Objects by comparing id if matches change isreccommende:true

Tags: javascript

```
var array =[{
        "_id": "5b7229fd5fd0b77763cd5d0b",
        "title": "Nexus of knowledge",
        "isRecommended":false,
       },
    {
        "_id": "5b7229d15fd0b77763cd5adc",
        "title": "Nexus of knowledge",
        "isRecommended":false,
       },
    {
        "_id": "5b7229c45fd0b77763cd5a11",
        "title": "Nexus of knowledge",
        "isRecommended":false,
       },
    {
        "_id": "5b7229be5fd0b77763cd59b9",
        "title": "Nexus of knowledge",
        "isRecommended":false,
       },
    {
        "_id": "5b7229be5fd0b77763cd59bf",
        "title": "Nexus of knowledge",
        "isRecommended":false,
       },
    {
        "_id": "5b7229c15fd0b77763cd59fb",
        "title": "Nexus of knowledge",
        "isRecommended":false,
       },
    ];

    var array2 = [
    {"_id": "5b7229c15fd0b77763cd59fb"},
    {"id":"5b7229be5fd0b77763cd59bf"},
    {"id":"5b7229be5fd0b77763cd59b9"}
    ];
    varResultArray = [{
        "_id": "5b7229fd5fd0b77763cd5d0b",
        "title": "Nexus of knowledge",
        "isRecommended":false,
       },
    {
        "_id": "5b7229d15fd0b77763cd5adc",
        "title": "Nexus of knowledge",
        "isRecommended":false,
       },
    {
        "_id": "5b7229c45fd0b77763cd5a11",
        "title": "Nexus of knowledge",
        "isRecommended":false,
       },
    {
        "_id": "5b7229be5fd0b77763cd59b9",
        "title": "Nexus of knowledge",
        "isRecommended":true,
       },
    {
        "_id": "5b7229be5fd0b77763cd59bf",
        "title": "Nexus of knowledge",
        "isRecommended":true,
       },
    {
        "_id": "5b7229c15fd0b77763cd59fb",
        "title": "Nexus of knowledge",
        "isRecommended":true,
       },
    ];
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @Ibo I think the question is simple. Just confused due do incorrect formatting.

Comment: Sorry for this format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop over `array2` and check if there is an object that exist in `array1` using `Array.find()`. Then you can change the `isRecommended` of that found object to `true`:

```js
var array1 = [{
  "_id": "5b7229fd5fd0b77763cd5d0b",
  "title": "Nexus of knowledge",
  "isRecommended": false,
}, {
  "_id": "5b7229d15fd0b77763cd5adc",
  "title": "Nexus of knowledge",
  "isRecommended": false,
}, {
  "_id": "5b7229c45fd0b77763cd5a11",
  "title": "Nexus of knowledge",
  "isRecommended": false,
}, {
  "_id": "5b7229be5fd0b77763cd59b9",
  "title": "Nexus of knowledge",
  "isRecommended": false,
}, {
  "_id": "5b7229be5fd0b77763cd59bf",
  "title": "Nexus of knowledge",
  "isRecommended": false,
}, {
  "_id": "5b7229c15fd0b77763cd59fb",
  "title": "Nexus of knowledge",
  "isRecommended": false,
}];
var array2 = [{
  "_id": "5b7229c15fd0b77763cd59fb"
}, {
  "_id": "5b7229be5fd0b77763cd59bf"
}, {
  "_id": "5b7229be5fd0b77763cd59b9"
}];

array2.forEach((item) => {
  var array1Obj = array1.find(({_id}) => item._id === _id);
  if(array1Obj) {
    array1Obj.isRecommended = true;
  }
});
console.log(array1);
```